# XAML: Image should show specific bitmap frame

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, bitmap

The following is a short piece that should help you to understand my misery ;(
I am trying to show a specific bitmap frame (Tif page) in the image control. But I cannot find any appropriate members of the image control.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage 
            DecodePixelWidth="500"
            UriSource="C:\...\MultiPage.tif" 
            CacheOption="OnLoad" 
            CreateOptions="PreservePixelFormat"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
            RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
            <!--The following line does not work of course but it should show what I mean:-->
            BitmapFrameIndex="3" 
        />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in code using the [`TiffBitmapDecoder` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx), but I'm not so sure that it can be done purely in XAML. The [`TiffBitmapDecoder.Frames` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.frames(v=vs.110).aspx) provides access to the individual frames from the image:

```
TiffBitmapDecoder tiffBitmapDecoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(filename), 
    BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
```

Then you can access a single frame like this:

```
BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = tiffBitmapDecoder.Frames[yourRequiredIndex];
```

Or create a `BitmapSource` instance from it instead:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = tiffBitmapDecoder.Frames[yourRequiredIndex];
```

As the [`BitmapSource` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx) extends the `ImageSource` class, you should then be able to set this directly as the `Image.Source` value:

```
YourImage.Source = bitmapSource;
```

Comment: @NoelWidmer You may perhaps wrap this in a derived BitmapSource to make it usable in XAML.